# JQuery UI Sortable content drags off screen forever

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Im using JQuery UI Sortable to move some widgets around the screen. However if you take the widget and drag it to the left, it will continue to go off the screen until you stop.

Is there any way around this?

```
$(".dashboardItems").sortable({
                    handle: "h3",    
                    placeholder: {
                        element: function (currentItem) {
                            return $("<div class='col-md-4'>"
                        },
                        update: function (container) {
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: I managed to fix this using containment: '.someClass' and then setting this class to have the css attributes overflow-x:hidden